# Trouble with Malloc for Structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I keep constantly getting a segmentation error with a small portion of code and I have no idea why, I'm using malloc and cant see any reason with that, just as soono as it hits the portion of data, its crashes.
The Data is:

```
listNode* node = (listNode*)malloc(sizeof(listNode));    <-This is the Line
strcpy(node->entry, string); 
node->next = NULL;
```

Using the struct definition:

```
typedef struct
{
    char* entry;
    struct listNode* next;
}listNode;
```

The data does get freed at one point, however it cannot reach said point.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You allocated memory for the struct itself. But you didn't for pointers that at in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't allocate memory for the `entry` pointer. You're trying to copy your `string` to a bogus location specified by the uninitialized pointer `entry`. You might do this instead:

```
node->entry = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);
strcpy(node->entry, string);
```

Comment: or `node->entry = strdup(string);`

Comment: oops, Didn't even notice that hehe, I'm to use to it throwing segmentation faults for data I should be using haha, thanks!

Comment: @John3136 if it's available. It's not in the C standard from 1999.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're crashing on the `malloc` call?  It's much more likely that you're crashing on the `strcpy`.  In fact, the `strcpy` in this case is almost *guaranteed* to cause bad behavior, although to be precise the behavior is undefined.

The `malloc` should succeed as long as you haven't filled up your heap.  However, because you called `malloc` and not `calloc`, you have no guarantees about the contents of `node->entry`.  The C standard doesn't define what is stored in memory allocated with `malloc`, so `node->entry` is filled with garbage.  By trying to copy to a bad pointer, your app is crashing for attempting to accessing an incorrect memory address.

Alexey Frunze is 100% correct on the fix - `malloc` space and change `node->entry` to point at the newly allocated memory, *then* copy `string` into `node->entry`.  This avoids undefined behavior for using an uninitialized pointer, as I described in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9815887/960195).

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating allocate memory for the entry pointer. as while allocationg structure just 4 bytes allocated for *entry pointer 
you should do

listNode* node = (listNode*)malloc(sizeof(listNode)); // allocate memory for structure
node->entry = malloc(strlen(string) + 1);// allocate memory for string
strcpy(node->entry, string); //copying strings

now it will run fine